# Android PrintHelper Orientation

Tags: android, printing, android-print-framework

I am using `PrintHelper` API provided by android 19 and above for wireless printing, using following code which is supposed to set preview to landscape according to code but actually its showing preview in portrait mode. Any help would be appreciated

Please refer Android code used for printing below

```
        PrintHelper printHelper = new PrintHelper(context);
        printHelper.setOrientation(PrintHelper.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        printHelper.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
        printHelper.setColorMode(PrintHelper.COLOR_MODE_MONOCHROME);
        printHelper.printBitmap("testPrint", bitmap);
```